# Error: Expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++

In the following code the compiler is showing error in second line while if I am not using a template class and explicitly defining V then it works fine.

```
template <class T,template <class T> class V>
void struct inp<T, V >::input(ifstream& in, V<T> lst)
```

Comment: void *struct* !?! are you sure about this?

Comment: In C++ it's not neccessary to put struct before the struct name as in C

Comment: Did you `#include <fstream>` and `use namespace std;`? The compiler simply doesn't know that `ifstream` is a type name; all the rest is a red herring.

Comment: You shouldn't use the name `T` here: `template<class T> class V`. There's no benefit from it, and it hides the first template parameter.

Comment: if this is doing what I think it is, when you fix you current problem  you'll find the vector your passing in takes two template parameters, not one. May as well think about that too.

Comment: The compiler is right, your code is nonsense. If you add anything on what you're trying to achieve we might be capable of helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have both `void` *and* `struct` in your template declaration.  Are you talking about a templated function or a templated class?  And you probable want a `const` ref to that `ifstream` and at least a non-const refernce to your templated class template parmater. You want either a class:

```
template <class T,template <class T> class V>
struct inp<T, V >::input(const ifstream& in, V<T>& lst)
```

or a function:

```
template <class T,template <class T> class V>
void inp<T, V >::input(const ifstream& in, V<T>& lst)
```

Comment: I am utterly failing to see how the first of these is even an option. You can't have just `struct` as a ***return type***. The second, however, is entirely conceivable.

Comment: You probably *don't* want to have a `ifstream` **const** reference, because you couldn't read from it then.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok you can have a function returning a `struct` but you don't state it that way.

Comment: @DyP of course you can *read* from a `const`, it's *write* you're thinking of.

Comment: @PaulEvans I stated it *exactly* how you wrote it. That line won't even compile. You can certainly have a function return a *type* that is a `struct`. but `struct` in itself is not a type.

Comment: No, I mean "read" in the sense of *getting the input from the input stream*. Those member functions (e.g. `operator>>`) are non-const, because they alter the observable state of the `ifstream`.